# Publishing pictures to Twitter via python

Tags: python, twitter

Is anyone using the twitter module for python (https://github.com/sixohsix/twitter/tree/master) able to publish pictures on twitter account? Everything works fine with publishing text to status, but I couldn't figure how to publish pictures. Thanks for the help.

Adding my code, as suggested in the comments (thanks for that!):

```
import twitter

t = twitter.Twitter(auth=twitter.OAuth('PAR1', 'PAR2','PAR3', 'PAR4')) #autentication is fine.

#t.statuses.update(status="Hello World!") #this command works fine!

t.updateStatusWithMedia('http://url_of_image', status="Hello World!") #that's what I need to do.
```

Comment: Please post your attempts, so we can see what are you doing wrong.

Comment: I edited my question with the code. Thanks @alKid.

Comment: From the docs, i don't see that there's a way to do this. Where do you get your method?

Comment: From other users in the internet that had the same attempt. I also don't see there's a way, so my question is here exact because of that. If you have any idea of how I can go through it, I apreciate, if you haven't, its ok. I can't understand the "-1" in my question.

Comment: Now, a question. Does this code triggers an error?

Comment: The error says that the parameters are wrong, what is not a surprise.
TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)

I would like to know if someone knows how to do this, to publish picture on the status.

Comment: I just found Twython, maybe it has a solution. Thank you tough.

https://twython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

If it works, I'll post here.

Comment: Just comment here if you need to ask me! :)

Comment: use t.statuses.update_with_media with args as described here https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update_with_media

Comment: Thank you so much, @alko. I guess the twitter module doesn't deal with the method POST, or I couldn't make it work. I could do it with:

import twython
import urllib

t = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET,OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
pic urllib.urlopen('http://pic.png')
t.update_status_with_media(status='Status', media=pic)

Thank you so much for your answer, alko.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the external `twitter` module, I assume that installing other external libraries is acceptable to you. You could try `tweetphoto` to upload images via an API. You can figure it out [here](http://code.google.com/p/python-tweetphoto/).

Comment: Thank you! I'm gonna try it too.

Comment: Glad that I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the twitter module doesn't deal with the method POST, or I couldn't make it work. I could do it with Twython:

```
import twython
import urllib

t = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET,OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
pic urllib.urlopen('http://pic.png')
t.update_status_with_media(status='Status', media=pic)
```