# Python Unitttest for twitter bot

Tags: python, unit-testing

I working on simple twitter bot on Python. Every day my bot is unfollowing people that do not follow me. How can I write unit tests for methods `follow` and `unfollow`,that doesn't change real account's followers?
And the second problem: Twitter can block my account if I will often add and remove friends.

EDIT:

```
from twython import Twython, TwythonError
class Twitbot(Twython):
    ....
    def unfollow_who_not_follow_back(self):
        #get friends ids
        friends_ids = self.get_friends_ids()[u"ids"]
        #get followers ids
        followers_ids = self.get_followers_ids()[u"ids"]
        #unfollowing list
        destroy_list = [user_id for user_id in friends_ids 
                        if user_id not in followers_ids] 
        map(self.destroy_friendship, destroy_list)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    twitter = TwitBot(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET,
                      OAUTH_TOKEN,OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
    twitter.unfollow_who_not_follow_back()
```

I special pass some try_except blocks.

Comment: You might try something like this [test suite](https://gitorious.org/twitter-api-test-suite), although I don't know how well it's kept up to date.

Comment: Please post your code so far. Also, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19729532/publishing-pictures-to-twitter-via-python/19737316#19737316 for a few ideas.